# A question about powers of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

Can someone help me in this problem?

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers with $p < q$.

1. There exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for which $1+p+p^2+...+p^m$ is a power of $q$.
2. There exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ for which $1+q+q^2+...+q^n$ is a power of $p$.

Prove that $p = 2, q = 2^t - 1$, with $t$ being a prime number.

Comment: It seems like this should be directly related to perfect numbers, but I can't see how yet...

Comment: See [theorems about Mersenne numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersene_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers).